# Check if the user is authenticated on not secured route

Tags: silex, symfony-security

I'm trying to build a simple login using `symofny/security` package in Silex, but I have a small problem with authentication checking.

The structure:

```
/
/login
/admin
    /login_check
    /logout
```

In order to get to the `/admin` route user needs to be authenticated, if he's not, he gets redirected to `/login` form, which then, as recommended, is asking `admin/login_check` for authentication (that's all provided by symofny's security firewalls).

The firewalls configuration:

```
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'login' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/login$',
    ),
    'admin' => array(
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login'
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
            'invalidate_session' => true
        ),
        'users' => ...
    ),
)
```

Everything works fine, but the user can enter the `/login` route even-though he's already authenticated, which is not that bad, but I'd like to avoid it. I tired to check the user authentication status, but I guess it does not work as I'm checking it on `/login` controller, which is not in "secured" area of the website.

Here's the code:

```
public function index(Request $request, Application $app)
{
    if ($app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
        return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('admin'));
    }
    return $app['twig']->render('login/index.twig', array(
        'error'         => $app['security.last_error']($request),
        'last_username' => $app['session']->get('_security.last_username'),
    ));
}
```

That throws an error: `The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.` So, the question, is there any way to do this using `symfony/security` natively (without any walk-arounds)? or is it somehow possible to create the `/login` route inside secured area with possibility to access it even-though the user is not logged in (e.g. make an exception for GET request) which would solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

I've also added the firewall configuration for `/login` page with an option `anonymous: true`, which resulted in not throwing an error anymore, but yet, when I'm logged in on the `/admin` route, method `isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` results in `true`, whereas on `/login` route it results in `false` (I'm still logged in there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily understand the behavior of the security component by dumping the current token.

```
public function index(Request $request, Application $app)
{
    var_dump($application['security.token_storage']->getToken());
}
```

When you don't set `anonymous` option for login page (by default it is `false`):

```
null
```

When you set `anonymous` option for login page to `true`:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken)
    private 'secret' => string 'login' (length=5)
    private 'user' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken) => string 'anon.' (length=5)
    private 'roles' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken) => 
        array (size=0)
            empty
    private 'authenticated' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken) => boolean true
    private 'attributes' (Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AbstractToken) => 
        array (size=0)
           empty
```

Following example describes why you are getting error in your initial code example.

## How to share security token?

To share security token between multiple firewalls you have to set the same [Firewall Context](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#firewall-context).

`SecurityServiceProvider` registers context listener for *protected* firewall you have declared with pattern `security.context_listener.<name>`. In your example it is registered as `security.context_listener.admin`. Thus context you want to use is named `admin`.

Also a firewall context key is stored in session, so every firewall using it must set its `stateless` option to `false`.

What is more, to invoke authentication on login page the `anonymous` option must be set to `true`

```
'security.firewalls' => array(
    'login' => array(
        'context' => 'admin',
        'stateless' => false,
        'anonymous' => true,
        'pattern' => '^/login$',
    ),
    'admin' => array(
        'context' => 'admin',
        'stateless' => false,
        'pattern' => '^/admin',
        'http' => true,
        'form' => array(
            'login_path' => '/login',
            'check_path' => '/admin/login'
        ),
        'logout' => array(
            'logout_path' => '/admin/logout',
            'invalidate_session' => true
        ),
        'users' => ...
    ),
)
```

After the change, if you are logged in on admin panel and login page you will get an instance of `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken` as a token and 
`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\AnonymousToken` if you are not logged in.

Because of that, you can safely check permission using `$app['security.authorization_checker']->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')` and get the same results on both firewalls.

Comment: You're awesome, thanks! Finally someone found some time to explain. I understood the part with firewalls after I read it once again, but I found nothing about context in Silex symfony/security docs. I could've read the symfony's one, never mind. Thank's once again.

Comment: Right, the documentation is poor when it comes to this matter. I can only recommend reading the code https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Providers/blob/master/SecurityServiceProvider.php

Comment: I did contribute to the silex documentation right after you answered the question, but it's still waiting for the approval, so we'll see.